# Stop new branch from getting old commit history in Git

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I had this structure in Git

```
develop      C - D - E
            /
master A - B
```

Then, I added a new branch from develop with:

```
git checkout -b new_branch develop
```

This is what i got

```
new_branch C - D - E - F - G
                      /
develop      C - D - E
```

It branched off, but new branch inherited the commit history of develop, instead of the desired structure:

```
new_branch        F - G
                 /
develop C - D - E
```

How could I achieve this?

Edit: develop log output

```
* 0c5b5fe Deleted changelog
* b20083f Added changelog. Version 1.2 Development
*   b9d888b Merge branch 'ProgressHUD' into develop
|\  
| * e310630 Modified .gitignore to ignore Instrument Tests
| * 9bb7ab7 Deleted code to remove "deletion while loading" functionality.
| * d139fef Fixed a few errors with RecentPhotos loading.
| * 6d52eb1 Added MBProgressHUD to the recents section
| * d98e09e Added MBProgressHUD functionality in the PersonList
| * 4c6fd41 Added MBProgressHUD Files.
* | 2f741e3 Modified .gitignore
|/  
*   ea1b51b Merged in glenwayguy/gitignore-edited-online-with-bitbucket-13693489
|\  
| * bdb0996 .gitignore edited online with Bitbucket
|/  
* 0fb68ec Initial Commit Version 1.1 Release
```

new_branch log output:

```
* 0c5b5fe Deleted changelog
* b20083f Added changelog. Version 1.2 Development
*   b9d888b Merge branch 'ProgressHUD' into develop
|\  
| * e310630 Modified .gitignore to ignore Instrument Tests
| * 9bb7ab7 Deleted code to remove "deletion while loading" functionality.
| * d139fef Fixed a few errors with RecentPhotos loading.
| * 6d52eb1 Added MBProgressHUD to the recents section
| * d98e09e Added MBProgressHUD functionality in the PersonList
| * 4c6fd41 Added MBProgressHUD Files.
* | 2f741e3 Modified .gitignore
|/  
*   ea1b51b Merged in glenwayguy/gitignore-edited-online-with-bitbucket-13693489
|\  
| * bdb0996 .gitignore edited online with Bitbucket
|/  
* 0fb68ec Initial Commit Version 1.1 Release
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have commits C, D, and E in two different lines of commits.  The command `git checkout -b new_branch develop` should've have given you what you wanted.  Does the output of `git log --graph new_branch` actually show you what you described above?

Comment: Yes, it does show what I described above.

Comment: If you delete `new_branch` and run `git checkout -b new_branch develop`, do you still get the same result?  Also, can you show us the log output of your your `develop` branch (with `--graph --oneline` options)?  Are the commit shas different?

Comment: Yes, they both have the same log output and the same SHAs

Comment: `develop` and `new_branch` have the same log output?  Can you show us?  It would really help in trying to figure out what's going on and solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are interpreting the output of `git log` incorrectly.

This is not the correct picture

```
new_branch C - D - E - F - G
                      /
develop      C - D - E
```

Commits C, D and E are *identical*, and should not be shown in two different places.

This is what you desire, and it is indeed what you have

```
new_branch        F - G
                 /
develop C - D - E
```

Perhaps you expect the output of `git log` on `new_branch` to stop at F, but that is not the way `git log` works, it will show a continuous chain of commits and their parents. This chain starts at the current branch, but further back, it does not care what branch the commits "belong" to (a branch is actually just a pointer to a specific commit).

If you want the log history of just `new_branch` excluding the commits on `develop`, you have to tell `git log` that explicitly, like this:

```
git log develop..new_branch
```

This will list commits F and G.

Comment: We are all beginners sometime. I personally feel the output of `git log` is a bit hard to parse for a human. Try `gitk --all` instead. `gitk` gives a graphical and more understandable output. The `--all` flag is good for beginners, it shows all branches not just your current one.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I just started learning to use Git yesterday and I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: @glenwayguy since you're learning, make sure you read the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), especially chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5.  It's free, and it taught me most of what I needed to know about using Git.  Learn how to `rebase` too, both interactively and non-interactively; in my opinion, `rebase` is the single most important command you need to know in order to use Git effectively.  Also, [the reference documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs) tends to be really good.